# Is a soft boiled egg fully cooked?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cooking-bishul, eggs

On Shabbos, Chazarah, which is returning something onto the fire, is permitted if it was fully cooked already (among other conditions that have to be met)although it is Mitstamek v'yofe lo.

Is a soft boiled egg considered fully cooked which would allow its return onto the fire on Shabbos?

Comment: I don't yet have proof to back up my opinion, here. But FWIW, when I was in summer camp numerous years ago, we could never get soft boiled eggs on Shabbat, apparently for just this reason. I.e. - no one would ever eat a cold soft-boiled egg. The hard boiled eggs were warm. It seems that warming the soft boiled egg would cook it so that it became harder.

Answer (score 2):

Rabbi Ribiat in "The 39 Melochos" volume 2 page 595 based on Rabbi Shlomo Zalman Auerbach quoted in Shemiras Shabbos K'Hilchasa Chapter 1 note 148 says that it is questionable whether one may place a soft boiled egg into hot water since it will continue to cook and one is hardening something that is soft (which may apply to food). However He allows it if the water is not so hot and if one is not attempting to harden it. So if one is just warming it it seems like it would be permitted on Shabbos if reheated in a Kli Shlishi.

Comment: So I guess the second part of the question is since, no, a soft boiled egg is not fully cooked, don't cook ot by putting it in any knd of heated situation, because then it would be cooking on Shabbos.

Comment: I've never run a science experiment on this, but, my hunch is that the temp of a *kos shlishi* would still initially be hot enough to cause some hardening of the white, at least. (It can be easily proven that albumen hardens much more quickly than the yolk. Look what happens with fried eggs.) Thus, I wonder how using a *kos shlishi* would solve this problem.

Answer (score -1):

A kli shlishi is fine because even though an egg is kalay habishul, it is mutter in a kli shlishi as per R Moshe Feinstein